# Is it a good idea to pass IdentityUser object to other controller from View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

In primary controller action method I do the following to get a current ApplicationUser object (it inherits from IdentityUser):

```
[Authorized]
     ...
 var user =   await (UserManger<..>)userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)
```

The object would need in View, so I pass it to ViewData:

```
ViewData["User"] = user;
```

In the View I want to display some auxiliary information about current user:

```
@{
    ApplicationUser user = (ApplicationUser)ViewData["User"];
    int UnreadMessages = OtherController.GetTotalUnreadMsgs(user); 
}
```

Therefore I need  ApplicationUser object in the View. I pass it to method of other controller. This method uses DbContext to get information from DB (context object is Scoped, single per the request).

My question: is it safe? Does exist any better practice?

Comment: Why can't you call that method from within the controller, and assign the result to the original model for the view you are in?

Comment: Stop mixing concerns. extract all the information you want in the controller and pass it to the view via a viewmodel. That is what they are for. stop trying to do controller concerns in the view. The code smells of poor design.

Comment: This  auxiliary information about User may be not needed in View (depending some conditionals). So for performance I do not get it in primary controller's method. I think it is not good idea but is there any variants? It looks like attempting display current time in View (and calling appropriate method for it) but one needs db-connection in my case

Comment: You can call the method through AJAX and then handle the response in JavaScript, but ideally it's either that, or put the conditional part of that into the original controller. I wouldn't recommend calling the controller method from the view directly either way...